# Core Data: "-add<RelationshipKey>Object:" not called

Tags: macos, core-data

Let's presume I have an entity `BikeRider` with a relationship property called `helmets`.

I have an array controller bound to the app's managed object context, with entity set to `BikeRider`. There's a tableview that lists all bike riders.

Then, I have a second array controller, bound to the app's managed object context, with entity set to `Helmet`. Additionally, it's bound to `bikeRiderArrayController.selection`. There's a second tableview that lists all helmets for the selected bike rider.

I also have two buttons for adding and removing helmets. The setup works apparently flawlessly.

Except, of course for one small thing: it looks like `-addHelmetsObject:`, `-removeHelmetsObject:`, `-addHelmets:` and `-removeHelmets:` never get called. This means some code for setting up observation of each helmet's `color` property never gets called.

**What am I missing?** Isn't overriding `addHelmets:` et al (with proper `willChangeValueForKey:` et al notifications) the right way to get notified of additions?

**Do I really have to** `[self observeValueForKey:@"helmets". . .]` and then `[oldValue minusSet:newValue]` and vice versa to figure out which objects were added or removed? I could swear the methods were being correctly called in the past. Maybe some key element of the setup is now different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has never worked properly through NSArrayController. From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002320-SW22):

> ### Custom relationship set mutator methods are not invoked by an arraycontroller
>
> **Problem:** You have implemented set mutator methods for a relationship as described in “Custom To-Many Relationship Accessor
>   Methods,” and have bound the contentSet binding of an
>   NSArrayController instance to a relationship, but the set mutator
>   methods are not invoked when you add objects to and remove objects
>   from the array controller.
>
> **Cause:** This is a bug.
>
> **Remedy:** You can work around this by adding self to the contentSet binding's key path. For example, instead of binding to [Department
>   Object Controller].selection.employees, you would bind to [Department
>   Object Controller].selection.self.employees.

Comment: I knew there was a reason why I made it a habit to add those `self`s. Too bad I could never remember it. Thanks!